# Looking for html input attribute or bootstrap class where i can fix the data type conflict issue

Tags: html, mysql, database, bootstrap-4, codeigniter-3

I am building an CodeIgniter webapp.Now the problem is to apply text limit. I can not use the `maxlength=""` attribute because in my database table i did define fields for this `<input>` element type is date. i mean as you can see it is a numeric data type but in my database table i declare for this `<input>` is date.
   Now i am looking for `html` attribute or any bootstrap class where i can fix this issue. i hope i explain the scenrio very clearly.

**Code is below:**

```
<div class="col-md-5">
<div class="input-group date 24hourtime">
<input type="text" class="form-control mytime" value="<?php echo 
empty($work_hr_start)?"":$work_hr_start;?>" id="txtfromtime" 
name="txtfromtime" required />                                                                                       
<span class="input-group-addon">                                                                                             
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
</span>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way you may do this with few step.
**1. Set input field type `date`**
**2. Set a `max` date**
**3. Validation date is over then do something..**

```js
    //validate date in onchange state
    document.getElementById("date").onchange = function ()
    {
      var dateField = document.getElementById("date");
      if(dateField.value > dateField.getAttribute("max")){ //check date in range
        dateField.value = dateField.getAttribute("max"); //action
      }
    }
```

```html
 <!--HTML-->
 <p>With date field and set <b>max</b> date(2020-01-01).<p> 
 <form>
     <input id="date" type="date" name="date" value="" max="2020-01-01">
     <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: your answer show me many things to learn. but i wanna ask little more about. as you can see in my code i am using bootstrap. now is there any class in bootstrap that i can solve this issue.

Comment: and your code work fine in my webapp but i need boostrap look. so i can't face problems with all browser.

Comment: Hi, @stackOverFlowGeek thank you for interesting to bootstrap. You can look  [bootstrap date picker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io) maybe it's help you to gain.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can use the `maxlength` attribute of `<input>` element but with the **zero** value.so now user can't input other date or time.